# QT Creator on Ubuntu using GCC and GDB - Debugging C++ - More verbose segmentation fault messages

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb, qt-creator

I'm relatively new to working on Linux, so I may be overlooking something simple.

On Windows if my program causes a segmentation fault I'm used to getting a pop-up with some useful information. Something to the effect of: `Access violation reading/writing/executing memory at address 0x****`, `Stack overflow`, etc.

On Linux debugging through QT Creator all I'm getting is:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.    
Signal name : SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

Is there a way to make these messages give the same information that is present in their windows counterparts, or at least the type of fault (memory violation, stack overflow, etc.)? I can of course debug the program with GDB, but this pop-up usually gives me a good idea of what the problem is very quickly, versus having to dig around the crash site.

Comment: The OS handles access violations and other sources of "SEGFAULT", so unless your Linux distro lets you tweak this (I dont know if it is even possible really), you'll have to open the coredump with gdb, where you'll find much more information on the source of the fault.

Comment: @quantdev I thought that was the case, though I thought it odd that on Linux I only get a pop-up when running through QT Creator (where as on windows I will get a pop-up regardless of if I am in Visual Studio or not). I wasn't quite sure if this pop-up was the work of the OS or someone else along the line being informed by the OS (thus the potential that if it is QT Creator causing the pop up, maybe it is receiving more info from the OS but just not providing it). Also added my reason for asking about this vs debugging in gdb without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, gdb doesn't try to interpret the reason for the crash.  I guess maybe it could do more here.

For more information about what exactly caused a crash you can look at $_siginfo.  There's a section on this in the gdb manual.  Unfortunately it's rather obscure.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this message from Qt Creator, it also fills the Stack view with data. In the top entry you usually see the address of the instruction that caused the bad access.

Comment: True. The reason I wanted a windows-style pop-up was to save seconds-minutes, depending on the issue. For example, segfaulting on a pointer access could mean a few things, meaning I'd have to go add a watch or look at the locals window to see if the address is NULL, garbage, or a known pattern (for example, uninitialized memory). Not a huge gain in almost all cases, and thus not a huge deal that there's no easy way to get it.